# Singularity Of $\frac{e^z-1}{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

$$f(z)=\frac{e^z-1}{z}$$

Taking the limit $$\lim_{z\to 0}(z-0)\frac{e^z-1}{z}=\lim_{z\to 0}z\frac{e^z-1}{z}=\lim_{z\to 0}{e^z-1}=0$$

On the other hand $$\frac{e^z-1}{z}=\frac{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}-1}{z}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{z^{n-1}}{n!}-\frac{1}{z}}=z^{-1}+1+\frac{z^2}{2}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+...-\frac{1}{z}=1+\frac{z}{2}+\frac{z^2}{3!}+...+$$

So which Singularity is it?

Comment: The second is wrong. Where is $1/z$ from?

Comment: @W.mu it is the first element of the series

Comment: You are cancelling the $-1$ wrongly.

Comment: @BrianYao but if the limit is zero it is a removable singularity

Comment: @mrf sorry, edited

Comment: @SaucyO'Path correct, Edited

Comment: The limit is the derivative of $e^z$ at $0$; can you compute it?

Answer (score 1):

$ \lim_{z \to 0}f(z)=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{e^z-1}{z}=1$, hence $f$ an a removable singularity at $0$ (by Riemann).